# Jquery indexed DB and redirect issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, indexeddb

Im looking for a bit of help.

I have a javascript login page which redirects a user on successful login (based on JSON response from server).

I want to be able to add a load of data to my indexeddb for use around the site instead of firing of ajax requests all the time; however my login script redirects the user before all of the data is stored in the db. (there can be quite a lot of it.)

I am looping through a response object like so:

```
var lookup = $.indexedDB("atlas").objectStore("Lookup");
lookup.clear();
$.each(obj, function(){
    lookup.add(this);
});
```

is there a way i can detect when the entirety of the above has completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but totally forgot about this thread.

I managed to fix this using the $.indexedDB().done() function that allows me to run code after the current cunning process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiaire with the plugin, but when working with the indexeddb spec you have a complete callback on the transaction. This is called when the transaction is completed and committed.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. i have implemented the callback as you described, i now have all my data add in this callback but for some reason it doesn't seem to insert all the data.. I will keep at it though.

Comment: What do you mean with not all the data? Are not all the objects inserted, or are objects missing properties? The sencond thing can be because it is a function. Only things that can be serialized to JSON can be stored in the indexeddb

Comment: they are JSON objects from a jSON ajax request, but not all of the object is being inserted into the IndexedDB; for example i have a lookup objectSTore with around 900 objects to stick in it. only around 100 of them are getting put in..

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small jquery plugin (still very alpha) to ease the use of the confusing IndexedDB API

https://github.com/ameyms/jquery-indexeddb

And I've tried to keep the API super simple:

```js
//Define and initialize an IndexedDB ...
var db = $.idb({
                    name:'foobar', 
                    version: 2,
                    drop: stores_to_be_deleted,
                    stores:list_of_stores
                });

// ... Add objects to a store
db.put(items, 'into_store').done(onsuccess);

//.. And delete objects from a store
db.remove('from_store', conditionFunc).done(onremoval);

//.. And not to forget fetching objects from a store
db.select('from_my_store', conditionFunc).done(function (items){

    console.log(items)
});
```

Hope you like it!